How autobreak long bibliography entry on many lines with spaces, not passing margin?
I compile by
xelatex main.tex
bibtex main.aux
xelatex main.tex
evince main.pdf

Body
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article} 
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\overfullrule=1mm
\pretolerance=-1
%\tolerance=1
%\badness=0

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


\printbibliography

\end{document}

bib2.bib -file
@article{2307111.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf,
    author = {Lorem lorem and Lorem Loremlorem},
    note = {230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf, 230711 lorem11 lorem.YHTEINEN TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf},
    date = {2023-07-11},
    title = {Mittausp\"{o}yt\"{a}kirja. Yhteisen tiealueen maaty\"{o}t 11.7.2023.}
}

Output

It floods to over the margin.
The problem is that the note fileds have long entries.
I have played with these parameters but nothing works:
\overfullrule=1mm
\pretolerance=-1
%\tolerance=1
%\badness=0

Try 1
I know the answer with \seqsplit{...} in the thread How to wrap a word in line without hyphen? but it does not maintain spaces, which I want.
Try 2: David
With \usepackage{xurl} and \path{...} does not maintain spaces.
Try 3: David, Mico
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}

bib2.bib file field
@misc{hello,
    author={Hello World},
    note = {\path{240228.[External]230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf, 230711 lorem11 lorem.YHTEINEN TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf, 230711 lorem11 lorem.YHTEINEN TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}
    },
    date = {2024-02-28}
    }

cfr try
Code
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,12pt,finnish]{article} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

%\usepackage{seqsplit}
%\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{xurl} % before biblatex
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % before hyperref 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\overfullrule=1mm
\pretolerance=-1
%\tolerance=1
%\badness=0

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

Hello world: 
\printbibliography

\end{document}

bib2.bib
@article{2307111.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf,
author = {Lorem lorem and Lorem Loremlorem},
note = {\path{230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}, \path{230711 lorem11 lorem.YHTEINEN TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}},
date = {2023-07-11},
title = {Mittausp\"{o}yt\"{a}kirja. Yhteisen tiealueen maaty\"{o}t 11.7.2023.}
}

@article{211110.heppuu.heppu.APUPOHJA.SUODATINRENGAS.NOTAARIUSKERROKSEN.PAKSUUS.pdf,
    author = {Heppuu Lassi},
    note = {
    \path{231110.heppuu.hukka.APUPOHJA.SUODATINRENGAS.NOTAARIUSKERROKSEN.PAKSUUS.pdf}
    },
    date = {2023-11-10},
    title = {Mittausp\"{o}yt\"{a}kirja. Tasolasermittaukset: apupohjan suodatinrenkaan korkeusasemat, notaariuskerroksen paksuus. 
    10.11.2021.}
}

Output where overflooding

but spaces still do not stay.
OS: Debian latest

Here are two earlier questions that dealt with similar problems: How to break long words after n chars (long genomic sequences) and How to wrap a word in line without hyphen?.  Or maybe someone has developed a way to treat this problem like an unlinked url.

never use \usepackage{t1enc} with anything and never use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with xelatex.

yes but what do you expect to happen?  you are trying to hyphenate nonsense strings such as 230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf  as English text and none of the hyphenation patterns match. Do you want hyphens added at the linebreak? do you just want to allow linebreak at . ? do you want to allow linebreak at any letter?  start by using \usepackage{xurl} and mark things up as \path|230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf|

@DavidCarlisle No need since technical jargon context. Yes, linebreak ok.

"but it does not maintain spaces", but your filename does not have spaces? Which spaces should it maintain?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, added example with spaces.

Easy solution: don't use spaces in file names

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Not my files. 1000+ such files and need to get them organised

@DavidCarlisle xurl proposal does not maintain spaces.

use the obeyspaces option to xurl package, or probably better obeyspaces,spaces see texdoc url

In support of @DavidCarlisle's suggestion, see also this answer and, in particular, the following passage: "If you want to allow line breaks to occur at spaces in a URL string, while not suppressing spaces elsewhere in the URL string, be sure to load xurl with the options spaces and obeyspaces." What you probably want to use is the package's. \path macro, not the \url macro (since the long strings aren't URLs).

@Mico See Try 3. I cannot get spaces stay with \path and options in url. Why?

You are loading things in the wrong order and not loading any hyphenation. But the real problem is that neither url nor xurl will help with a string which is not marked up as a URL or similar.  Is the string in the note field a URL?

You probably want this:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{2307111.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf,
    author = {Lorem lorem and Lorem Loremlorem},
    note = {\path{230711.lorem11.lorem.YHTEINEN.TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}, \path{230711 lorem11 lorem.YHTEINEN TIE.ALUE.HELLOWORLD.pdf}},
    date = {2023-07-11},
    title = {Mittausp\"{o}yt\"{a}kirja. Yhteisen tiealueen maaty\"{o}t 11.7.2023.}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{xurl}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\overfullrule=1mm
\pretolerance=-1
%\tolerance=1
%\badness=0

\usepackage{hyphenat}



\begin{document}
\nocite{*}


\printbibliography

\end{document}

Note that the order in which you load packages is critical here. xurl should be loaded before biblatex, which should be loaded before hyperref.
Also, you need to specify at least one language for your document. Right now, you are using no language, which Babel calls nil. This affects line breaking. Hyphenation patterns are language and variant specific. If you don't load the correct set, lines will get broken in the wrong places. If you don't load any, you will get a minimal US set and lines may not get broken at all.
Unless you have very strong reason not to, you should use biber rather than bibtex with biblatex. You will not get equivalent functionality with the deprecated bibtex backend.

My language setting is finnish. Still, it floods some long names. Etc 240417.OlavinosoitekenttaA1.Mi
OJA.VEDENPINTA.TODO-2_allekirjoitettu_matti2.TODO.pdf. Why?

@LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Example? Please edit your question or ask a followup if you still can't get it working. Does it work for you now with the entry in your original code? That name seems to have sufficient places to break, so I have no idea what's working or not working without code I can use to reproduce. I just answered this because I thought a complete example would be more helpful than comments talking past each other. I don't think it is a good idea to start a long series of comments with the same problem here.

I made one practical example in the body. Is that enough clear to demonstrate the problem?

@LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Oh, that's easy. You're still loading in the wrong order. xurl must be loaded after biblatex. Or you have to apply the settings manually to Biblatex.

Thank you! How do you turn those ending black boxes off?

@LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Well, they should disappear once you correct your code. But you should also remove draft when compiling the final version ;). By the way, 'Oh, that's easy' actually translates as 'I can actually answer this (and I didn't expect that!).'
